# Inheritance with generics + collection + method = question

Tags: java, generics, collections

I have some problem with generics and collection. Java support generics only at compilation level. So we can't use case B.

```
{
    foo(new HashSet<I>());  //case A
    foo(new HashSet<C>());  //case B: wrong
}
void foo(Set<I> set){}
class C implements I{}
interface I {}
```

So how we can use function foo with Set< C > parameter?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By changing the signature of Foo:

```
void foo(Set<? extends I> set){}
```

You won't be able to *add* values to the set within `foo`, but you'll be able to iterate over them or check for containment.

Answer (score 1):

Jon Skeet is right. If you did need to add something, however, you could write a generic function

```
public <T extends I> void foo2(Set<T> set, T added){set.add(added);}
```